# ubuntu 14.10 compix crash now no gui

Tags: gui

I installed the compix Configuration Managerhowever I never really utilized it. whenever I would shut my laptop screen I assumed suspend mode would initiate. Upon restart I received an error about compix crashing. So I tried to uninstall the compix manager in which I installed. I noticed in the software center that there were two compix programs installed. I'm new to about two ubuntu, new to Linux.  I uninstalled both and now after a restart my GUI menu and my terminal will not open. Any ideas?

will utilizing system repair from the installation disc correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Boot the computer and open one of the tty consoles with ctrl + alt + f1. This allows you to directly access the computer's terminal. Type your username and password to login, then run the command `sudo apt-get install compiz`, and enter your password when prompted. Then reboot the computer when done with `sudo reboot`. Your GUI should then be functional again.

Comment: Well, I successfully followed your instructions,  however after restart the menues do not show.  Ideas

Comment: Tried it again, says compiz is up to date...

Comment: @GlennRichards Really sorry about the delay, I need to check StackExchange more often. You're probably missing a package which apt automatically removed when you installed it because it was no longer needed anymore. You can repair your installation in many cases by using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Can you think of any other packages I may have deleted,  that may be needed? Because that installed, but still did not solve. ?.